# How to run a program in background through appveyor.yml?

Tags: appveyor

I have two exe's. One should be started as a server and open a pipe for interaction. Another would connect through this win pipe and run testing requests to it.

The problem is that after when I try to start programm1.exe in appveyor.yml script, I see no output and further instructions not being executed.

I need smth like this:

start programm1.exe --options
start programm2.exe --options
set output of programm2 to appveyor log
wait until programm2 finished
stop programm1

If you know how to do this, please share your experience, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Start-Process` and `Stop-Process` cmdlets to do that. You need to save started process information in variable to be able to stop it.

Here are how commands can look in appveyor.yml style:

```
install:
  - ps: $MyProcess = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru

on_finish:
  - ps: Stop-Process -Id $MyProcess.Id
```

Hope this helps.

--ilya

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!  Now power shell commands are working!